# MongoDB Multiple database vs single database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database

I have a NodeJS project that using mongodb as main database.
Regular, I just use one database for containing all information (users, organization, messages,...)

But now, I need to store one more thing - log data - which grow very very fast.
So I consider store log in other database to keep current database safe and fast.

Does anyone has experience in this, Is that better than single database?

Answer (score 0):

Not a real question the mods will certainly say. You have a few options depending on your log data and how / how often you want to access it.

- [Capped collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) if you don't need to store the logs for a long time
- Something like [Redis](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) to delay writing to the log and keep the app responding fast
- Use a replica set to distribute the database load.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, actually log data here is important and access very often. I consider that using separate database or same is better in this case.